# Выделение обстоятельства запятыми, как уточнения

Tags: уточнения, обстоятельство

Есть предложение: "Свинья за цикл жизни человека ни разу не видит". Без знаков препинания его можно трактовать двояко (за цикл жизни свиньи или человека?). Нужно ли (можно ли) здесь выделять обстоятельство "за цикл жизни" запятыми, как уточнение, или можно оставить как есть?

Answer (score 1):

Человека хорошо бы определить функционально (оператор, персонал), чтобы исключить проступающий философский настрой фразы. Но пока оставлю.

*В прижизненном цикле свиней животное не видит человека.*

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли можно выявить смысл этого предложения добавлением знаков препинания. Лучше изменить *порядок слов* исходя из гипотетического смысла: где-то выращивание свиней организовано по такой технологии, что свинья за свою жизнь не успевает увидеть человека. От слова "цикл" лучше отказаться: свинья циклов (или поколений выращенных свиней) не воспринимает, для неё это *единичный* опыт проживания до забоя.

> Свинья за время жизни ни разу не видит человека.

Comment: Предложение дано как пример. Вопрос заключается именно в возможности использования запятых в конкретном примере.

Comment: Запятые в этом конкретном примере в предложенном месте невозможны, но могут подойти **скобки**.